# Starting new port on Amazon Ec2 free tier for socket io

Tags: node.js, sockets, amazon-ec2, socket.io, port

I am using Amazon EC2 service for the web purpose.  I have a web application which is hosted on apache i.e port 80.  Now i am running a node instance on port 3000 and when i load my website.

```
 io.connect('http:IP ADDRESS:3000');
```

This code tries to connect to my port.  On server side my instance is started.  But when i load my we application, this doesnt connect to server.

I was wondering do i need to update my configuration or is there any network settings i need to do ?

Comment: Do you allow port 3000 in the security group your instance is running in? If you don't, external traffic will not be able to connect to that port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding your port in your defined security group.

Follow http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#concepts-security for more reference.